# # url section hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

Hi i have simple single page website with # sections. I am using # to hide and show sections.

For example; someurl/index.html/**#sectionOne**
There is div with "sectionOne" id, so i can show related section.

My question is there a way to prevent or replace **"/" path character** in url with **#** like;

someurl/index.html/**sectionOne** --> someurl/index.html/**#sectionOne**

Because it gives 404 of course.
i tried beforeunload, window on load, body on load but these didn't solve my problem.

This is simple example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.onload = function(event) {
        var hash = "about";
        $("section").hide();
        $("#" + hash).show();
    };

    $(".nav").click(function() {
        console.log("CLICK");
        var hash = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        console.log(hash);
        $("section").hide();
        $("#" + hash).show();
    });
});
```

```css
section {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li><a class="nav" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="about">
    <h1>ABOUT</h1>
    <p>About section</p>
</section>

<section id="services">
    <h1>SERVICES</h1>
    <p>Services section</p>
</section>

<section id="contact">
    <h1>CONTACT</h1>
    <p>Contact section</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo class could be used here:

```css
section {
  display: none;
}
#about:target,
#services:target,
#contact:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="nav" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="nav" href="#services">SERVICES</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="nav" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<section id="about">
  <h1>ABOUT</h1>
  <p>About section</p>
</section>

<section id="services">
  <h1>SERVICES</h1>
  <p>Services section</p>
</section>

<section id="contact">
  <h1>CONTACT</h1>
  <p>Contact section</p>
</section>
```

---

With regards to preventing an user from navigating away using `/` (let it be anything), I believe there is no easy way to accomplish from the *client-side alone*.

We could use `window.onbeforeunload` event and let a *dialog-box* to be displayed to keep the user in based on whether or not they want.

Another option which I see is to use [*React Router for client-side 404*](http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/guides/NotFound.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot but i didn't exactly mean that. What i want prevent user to enter "/" path character or if there is "/" path character instead of "#" hash, replace it with #.

someurl/index.html/about --> someurl/index.html#about

Comment: Got your point. With regards to preventing an user from navigating away using `/` (let it be anything), I believe there is no easy way to accomplish from the client-side alone. Updated the answer with few suggestions.